# bash script variable substitution problem

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that needs to check if a program is running.  The script uses parameter $1 to determine what program to look for and pass it to the pgrep command.

So, in my script test.sh I have a line:

```
pgrep -f $1
```

Let's say I have a program mypgrm running and it's PID is 100. If I run "test.sh mypgrm" I would expect it to output
100

Instead it outputs the PID of the running test.sh

I can tell that the script knows that $1 contains "mypgrm"

However, if I change the line in test.sh to:

```
pgrep -f "mypgrm"
```

it does output
100
as expected.

I have tried pgrep -f "$1", but that doesn't work either.

What am I missing?

Comment: `pgrep -f "$1" | grep -v "^$$$"`?

Comment: Try `pgrep -x "$1"` within your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because at the time your script is running it also
contains `mypgrm` in its name like that:

```
bash ./test.sh mypgrm
```

and therefore is reported by `pgrep -f`. You can filter it out like
that:

```
pgrep -f "$1" | grep -v "^$$\$"
```

or use a little trick and pass a name of the program in the form that
wouldn't be visible to pgrep:

```
./test.sh '[m]ypgrm'
```

Comment: Thanks - now it works.  But I don't understand what you mean:

Comment: I don't understand "at the time your script is running is also contains mypgrm in its name like that?

Comment: Add `ps aux | grep "$1"` and see that there 3 processes that contain `$1` (the program that you're looking for) in their names: the real program you're after, the bash script you're just running and an `grep` process.

Comment: Got it - Thanks!!!

Comment: If later in the test.sh script I add another line pgrep -f $1, it works. Strange

Comment: @gldrplt: not possible really, it'll behave just like the previous one unless of course the program you're looking for no longer exists and you only see your script's PID